# How to activate newly created input in JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function to create and activate text field:

```
function createInput( button, val ) {
  if (button.children().length == 0) {
      button.html('<input type="text" class="form-control newField" size="7" maxlength="3">');

      button.children('input').val(val);
      button.children('input').select();
  }
}
```

it works good,but I have another event and if someone press enter I want to choose and create the next field:

```
$("html").on("keydown", ".newField", function(e) {
    var $this = $(this), code = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if(code == 13) { 
        var newValue = $this.val();
        var header = $this.parents('table').children('thead').children('tr').children('th').eq( $this.parents('td').index() );

        var $nextBtn = $this.parents('tr').next().children('td').eq( $this.parents('td').index() );

        if (newValue.length > 0) {
            $nextBtn.click();
        }
    }
});
```

it works, it creates new text field, but doesn't activate the field. Looks like the select() function doesn't work.

Is there any chance to activate this field ?

Comment: Did you mean `focus`?

Comment: what do you mean by activate? focus?

Comment: no need for all those children chains when you can merge the selectors into one `find()`

Comment: I mean select. The field is selected only first time. Not, if i "click' by $nextBtn.click();

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want an element with the user's input to be placed onto the page each time the user presses enter key.

Here's a working example of that:

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var input = document.getElementById('input');

input.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {

  // If the key being pressed is ENTER and the input element isn't empty
  if (event.keyCode === 13 && input.value) {
    // Create the element
    var element = document.createElement('div');
    element.setAttribute('class', 'btn');
    element.innerHTML = input.value;

    // Insert onto the page
    container.appendChild(element);

    // Clear the input element
    input.value = "";
    input.scrollIntoView();
  }
});
```

```css
.btn {
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4.3px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  margin-bottom: 4.3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 14px;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

#container:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
<input id="input" placeholder="Type here, when done press [ENTER] Key">
```